# Install mysql 57 on OS Oracle Linux 6.9: Error: Package

Tags: mysql, linux

On OS Oracle Linux

```
Oracle Linux Server release 6.9
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="6.9"
ID="ol"
VERSION_ID="6.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 6.9"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:6:9:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 6"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=6.9
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=6.9
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
Oracle Linux Server release 6.9
```

I've tried to install, MySQL community server 5.7 running the commands below:

```
$ yum install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
$ yum install mysql-community-server
```

It returned the following error:

> Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>                  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
>       Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
>                  Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.0.1.el6_8.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>                      Not found
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>                  Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
>                      libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
>       Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>                  Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
>       Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>                  Requires: systemd

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find and install the packages that provide the missing libraries. You can use yum whatprovides to accomplish this:

```
yum whatprovides */glibc.so.6
yum whatprovides */libmysqlclient.so.16
yum whatprovides */libsasl2.so.3
```

If the above commands find any packages, then install them. If not, then you will have to investigate where to find them. Mind you, that can be very challenging

Comment: Unfortunately, Oracle mysql 57 did not install to Oracle Linux 6.9, case mysql 57 requires version lib 
glibc.x86_64 = 2.17, in Oracle Linux 6.9 only 2.12